# Algorithm to extract abbreviated word to its original word

Tags: algorithm, nlp, text-analysis

I am building a program to do some text analysis.

I'm guessing that unpacking an abbreviated word to its original word will improve the accuracy of my analysis.
But I have no idea to implement it. I've google searched a little but can't find any article or paper discussing this. (Or maybe I just don't know the right keyword to search)

Basically what I need is: Given a word W, find a word with the highest probability to be the unabbreviated version of W from a dictionary (list of unabbreviated word). Optionally, I want the algorithm to be compatible with Indonesian language.

My question is somewhat similar to this SO question: [A string searching algorithm to quickly match an abbreviation in a large list of unabbreviated strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304687/a-string-searching-algorithm-to-quickly-match-an-abbreviation-in-a-large-list-of) , but that question hasn't been answered, despite being asked in 2010.

So, any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Without any knowledge of Indonesian, my first step would be to obtain a list of common abbreviations, and simply do a dictionary lookup.

```
viz. => namely
i.e. => that is
fr.  => from
Fr.  => France, French
abbr. => abbreviated, abbreviation
```

How to decide which expansion to choose is a can of worms of its own.  The examples I could quickly come up with are nice in that they are different parts of speech, so pick the adjective where an adjective fits in the sentence; but in the general case, you just have to cope with the fact that some abbreviations are genuinely ambiguous, just like there are ambiguous words.  Maybe don't expand those at all, after all.

For abbreviations you don't have in the dictionary, I would simply look them up in a word list, perhaps with frequency and/or part of speech information so you can pick the most likely / most popular one if there are several prefix matches.  Absent that information, I would use the crude heuristic to always pick the shortest match.

Answer (score 1):

Context is everything with abbreviations. Your "highest probability" match is almost certainly going to the one where the context of the abbreviation matches the (intended) context of the expansion.

Of course, the issue is that there are so many possible contexts, as shown by certain abbreviations having dozens of possible expansions. There is also the difficulty of trying to define the context of an abbreviation.

You might be able to get away with limiting it to only say 10-20 different contexts, then doing a rather rough matching. I'm fairly sure it'll have a high error rate. It'll also require a lot of work to manually add/verify the contexts.